# iOS: How to convert raw file into .pkpass / Sign manifest.json with the pass certificate

Tags: ios, wallet

I'm trying to create a pass to add into apple wallet. I have my file ready and I want to convert the file into .pkPass file.

I tried using 'signinpass' tool from 'https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Passbook' and ran on Xcode but i'm not able to generate .pkpass file.

I know that .pkpass is just a zip file so can anyone advise me on how to sign manifest file, which has key/value pair of files and its hashcode with its pass certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I used 'SignPass'and used {path}/signpass -p {passfile}.pass/ -c { pass cert}
 provided in 
['https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/PassKit/'](http://'https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/PassKit/') and went through
['https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_passkit/'](http://'https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_passkit/')

and was able to generate .pkpass